# how to specify a module only get compiled and installed in userdebug build while not user build

Tags: android, android-source

I am developing an Android native service. I want to compile and install it only for `userdebug` builds. How to specify this? Thanks.

Will adding the package to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES_DEBUG` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PRODUCT_PACKAGES_DEBUG += some_package`, which will include `some_package` in `userdebug` and `eng` builds ([reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/8c73673e73121f8f08d0bb7bfe35f2047a46a7a4/target/product/base_system.mk#341)).

Alternatively, you can add the package directly to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` conditionally:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT),userdebug)
   PRODUCT_PACKAGES += some_package
endif
```